# Make height of image responsive to browser size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the images to resize to the height of the browser being viewed.
Ideally I am trying to get the height of the images to a max-height of 1100px, and scale down based on the height of the browser.

I have tried height 100% and height auto, but nothing is working.

Example page is here - http://www.trentmcminn.com/dev/albums/melanie-georgacopolous/

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 <div id="lane" style="top: 49px; width: 1328px;">


        <div id="album-intro" class="cell">

        <div class="wrap">

        <h1>
        Laura Myers </h1>
        <p>Financial Times, How To Spend It</p>
        <p>Founder of Atea Oceanie. Photographed in Knightsbridge, London, 2012. </p>

        </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cell">

    <img data-respond-to="height" data-presets="tiny,45,60 small,75,100 medium,360,480 medium_large,600,800 large,768,1024 xlarge,825,1100 huge,825,1100" data-base="http://trentmcminn.com/dev/storage/cache/images/000/027/laura," data-extension="jpg?1373373141" alt="laura.jpg" height="1100" width="825" src="http://trentmcminn.com/dev/storage/cache/images/000/027/laura,xlarge.jpg?1373373141" style="cursor: pointer;">

        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

block elements don't expand to fill a container vertically, so `height: 100%` and `height: auto;` won't do what you are wanting.

The way I've done this kind of thing using jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var height = $(window).height();

 if(height < 1100){
  $('img').css('height', height + 'px');
 }

 $(window).resize(function(){
  var height = $(window).height();
  if(height < 1100){
   $('img').css('height', height + 'px');
  }
 });
});
```

You can mess with the math when it sets the height depending on how you want it to look.

Comment: Thanks a lot worked brilliantly, however would you know how to resize it so it doesnt overflow underneath the footer?

Comment: i.e. the height is the height between the header and footer Example here - http://trentmcminn.com/dev/albums/orlando-salamanca-torres/

Comment: either get the height of your footer with jquery like `$('#footerId').height()` or just write down the static height of your footer and when the `height` variable gets set say `var height = $(window).height() - heightOfFooter`

Comment: Thanks Nick, i tried to add that to the code you detailed above but it seemed to break it and it stopped resizing based on browser window.  Really sorry im not so good at this....

Comment: so for simplicity, let's assume that the height of your footer is 50px. Since you don't want the img to overlap the footer you have to take that height into account. To do this, you can say `height = height - 50` right after you set `height` equal to the window height. Make sense?

Comment: yes theoretically this makes sense, however when I have tried to do this in the jQuery code provided it breaks.  eg - var height = $(window).height() - 40px; am i being stupid?

Comment: you have to get rid of the 'px' because you can't do math using a string. Don't worry, `.height()` returns the height in pixels already, so you just have to add the px at the end when you set the css height of the img.

Comment: Got ya - thanks, that worked but not how I intended, its cut 40px off the bottom but still the images are overflowing into the footer. - would you mind taking a look?  http://www.trentmcminn.com/dev/albums/melanie-georgacopolous/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34946/discussion-between-nick-and-jeremy)

Comment: No problems, thanks anyway Nick - I managed to tweak around it and sort it out - thank you for your help anyway - your original code got me on the road to success!